# What is the best way to store and parse a large list of items

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am doing a project that includes two large sets of data:

1. A list of ~100 items, each of which will need to be evaluated at some point during the program.
2. A mapping of ~10 names and their respective attributes (there can be multiple)

These are all constants that I need to interact with various APIs I am using in this project. What is the most pythonic way of storing and using this data? The options I am thinking of are:

1. Create `txt` files with all the data and use `open()` to get the data. I would then parse it during the running of the program.
2. Create a JSON file that stores the data. The structure would be something like:

[image]

3. Store the information in a database. I am not sure what the DB structure would look like.

What is the best way to store large amounts of information in Python? I am thinking #2 is the way to go.

Comment: Since when ~100 items is a large dataset? Did you make a typo?

Comment: Is it typical to have 100 item list in the code?

Comment: It is not typical to have data in the code, but 100 items is by no means a large dataset. As a matter of fact, you can store 100 items in whatever way you want. A JSON file is just fine.

Comment: Does it just come down to application then? Would JSON be easiest to parse in the code?

Comment: It _really_ does not matter. There are reading/writing libraries for all kinds of popular data formats.

Comment: "These are all constants" Then you can put them in a separate file as list and dictionary objects, and import it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys.